# PHP - XDebug on WAMP/XAMPP with Sublime Text - How to map to specific pages

Tags: php, xdebug

I setup xdebug to work with sublime text 3 on my WAMP server. The problem is, that when I go to:

```
Tools -> XDebug -> Start Debugging (Launch Window)
```

The window it launches is `localhost/nutri/` every time. This is a problem because I might need to debug `localhost/nutri/other_page.php` so I do this:

```
Tools -> XDebug -> Start Debugging (Launch Window)
```

So for example, say I need to launch the debugger on `localhost/nutri/otherpage.php`

but it opens the browser on the page:

```
http://localhost/nutri/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug
```

So the xdebug is configured right I think:

[enter link description here](https://i.gyazo.com/b4217203b1be2d8ddd739cbacd11afef.png)

Heres from php.ini:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "c:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.6.19\\zend_ext\\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log= "C:\\wamp\\tmp\\xdebug.log"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\\wamp\\tmp"
xdebug.collect_params = 4
xdebug.collect_return = on
xdebug.collect_vars = on
xdebug.show_local_vars = 3
```

Heres my sublime text project file:

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "test",
        "follow_symlinks": true,
    },
    {
        "path": "wp-content\\plugins\\genomics",
        "follow_symlinks": true,
    },
    {
        "path": "wp-content\\plugins\\decodify-members",
        "follow_symlinks": true,
    },
    {
        "path": "wp-content\\plugins\\decodify-terminology",
        "follow_symlinks": true,
    },
    {
        "path": "wp-content\\themes\\decodify",
        "follow_symlinks": true,
    }
],

"settings":
{
    "xdebug":
    {
        "url": "http://localhost/nutri/"
    },
    "sublime-view-in-browser": {
         "baseUrl": "http://localhost/nutri",
         "basePath": "C:\\wamp\\www\\nutri"
    }
}
```

theres nothing really interesting in the XDebug config file:

```
    // Example:
// "/absolute/path/to/file/on/server" : "/path/to/file/on/computer",
// "/var/www/htdocs/example/" : "C:/git/websites/example/"
"path_mapping": {

},

// Determine which URL to launch in the default web browser
// when starting/stopping a session.
"url": "http://localhost/nutri/",

// An IDE key is used to identify with debugger engine
// when Sublime Text will start or stop a debugging session.
//
// This package does not filter sessions by IDE key,
// it will accept any IDE key, also ones that do not match this configured IDE key.
// It is merely used when launching the default web browser with the configured URL.
"ide_key": "sublime.xdebug",

// Which port number Sublime Text should listen
// to connect with debugger engine.
"port": 9001,

// Show super globals in context view.
"super_globals": true,

// Maximum amount of array children
// and object's properties to return.
"max_children": 32,

// Maximum amount of
// variable data to initially retrieve.
"max_data": 1024,

// Maximum amount of nested levels to retrieve
// of array elements and object properties.
"max_depth": 1,
```

Is there a way to add a page variable to the path that xdebug uses to load pages?

EDIT:

I managed to get the keyboard shortcut to start the debugger and run the browser at the same time by adding this keybinding to my sublime.keymap file:

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+1"], 
  "command": "xdebug_session_start",
  "args": {
    "launch_browser" : true
  }
}
```

Which helps a lot, but I still can't figure out how to make it launch the right file. It always launches whats in my project file:

```
    "xdebug":
{
    "url": "http://localhost/nutri/"
}
```

which is the root page of my website. Is there a way I can add a variable to it like:

```
"url": "http://localhost/nutri/{$file}"
```